# Migrating Service Fabric .NET Core 3.1 app to .NET 6 resulting in UI rendering 404

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, azure-service-fabric

I've recently been trying to migrate an existing Service Fabric .NET Core 3.1 application that has a **Web API project**, **MVC UI project**, several **class libraries** and associated **tests projects**.

I've been following the Microsoft documentation [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) and applied the "Update the target framework", "Update package references" steps to all the projects in this application as those are the only steps relevant to my application, fixed any compilation errors/warnings and it's now building successfully.

I've successfully managed to run the application and tested the Web API project via postman and can verify everything works fine i.e. I can hit the enpoints and get responses.

I've then tried to hit my local UI environment via https://localhost:30000/ but this renders an immediate `404` error

My `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` files **havent changed from .NET core 3.1 to .NET 6** within the affected `UI` project.

The default routing is configured.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
      endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
             name: "default",
             pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
       endpoints.MapRazorPages();
})
```

But it's rendering `404`.

[image]

I'm not quite sure why hitting the above URL doesnt load the home page given the default route is configured.

I might be completely wrong here but my assumption is on Service Fabric as I believe something has changed but the documenation for this is quite poor in my opinion.

*Additional Information*

.NET SDK's installed locally on my machine:

- 3.1.423
- 6.0.402

Service Fabric development kit installed locally:

- 9.0.1107.9590 (Runtime version)
- 6.0.1107.9590 (SDK version)

Any help would be much appreciated

---

Here is the UI project package references:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.GuardClauses" Version="4.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="12.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="3.2.449" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" Version="6.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions" Version="6.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.SqlServer" Version="6.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.47.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.25.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.25.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.25.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Kestrel" Version="6.0.1107" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Configuration" Version="6.0.1107" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services" Version="6.0.1107" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build" Version="2.1.175" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Could you please share your `.csproj` package referenec file.

Comment: @Harshitha added package references

Comment: Both the Applications run on different ports. You need to right click on each project seperately and  click on `Set as Startup Project`, then run.

Comment: @Harshitha Yes, both the API and UI will run on different ports. That's always been the case. In terms of setting as startup project... in a service frabric app it's the service fabric application icon that should be set as the "Startup Project" as opposed to the web/api projects

Comment: hitting `https://localhost:30000/` should render the home page but as mentioned its yielding a 404 page not found

Comment: Is it `3000` or `30000` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249396/discussion-between-ousmane-d-and-harshitha).

Comment: Do you have app.MapControllers(); in your startup?

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli nope, I have just `.MapControllerRoute()` as shown in the post which sufficed in .NET Core 3.1 app and I think should suffice in .NET 6 too. `.MapControllers()` will rely on the user doing attribute routing (most commonly used in WebAPI controllers). The former uses conventional routing (most often used in an MVC application) which is what my UI web application is. an MVC web app

Comment: Are you setting AllowStatusCode404Response  ? Sometime it might be configuration error, see https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/434

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli Nope, not setting that anywhere in code. However, I've had the same asusmption as you... something might be masking the original error and making it seem as if its a user error.

Comment: It's hard to predict without sample. Can you try to setup empty template with .net6 and compare with yours? Making attention to order of methods as well, with .net core it's essential